# Почему постоянно выводит None?

Tags: python

Введите число до 1018:
None1
0
как убрать NONE

```
n = int(input(print("Введите число до 1018:")))
list = [i for i in range(1,n + 1)]
if n <= 1018:
    print(str(list).count('5'))
else: print("ERROR!")
```

Comment: В первой строке убери print, уберешь None, обычная невнимательность

Answer (score 3):

функция `print` ничего не возвращает, поэтому по питоновским правилам считается, что она возвращает `None`

функция `input` в качестве параметра может принимать текст, который она выводит своими силами

когда вы делаете код

```
input(print(текст))
```

происходит следующее:

1. функция `print` выводит текст и возвращает `None`
2. функция `input` берет то, что вернула функция `print`, т.е. `None`, и выводит на экран

поэтому вы и видите None на экране

поэтому используйте просто

```
input(текст)
```

если же вы использовали `print`, тогда код должен был бы выглядеть так:

```
print(текст, end='')
input()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ls = [i for i in range(1,n + 1)]
if n <= 1018:
    print(str(ls).count('5'))
else: print("ERROR!")
```

str(list) - вы используете зарезервированнео поле и получаете '[]'

Comment: он получает None не поэтому. а потому что присваивает переменной n результат выполнения команды print.

Comment: У него в list присвоено выше значение, проблема не в этом. Хотя само такое присваивание, конечно, тоже проблема.

Comment: Вижу, изначально этого не было написано. ДУмал челвоек не поймет почему у него 0